# PubSubClient ESP32 disconnected while receive message

Tags: c++, mqtt, esp32

I create a project to receive message from MQTT. My full code is here
https://github.com/kamshory/OTP-Mini/blob/main/Server/Server.ino

```c
WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);

void setup()
{
  char * mqttServer = "192.168.1.3";
  client.setServer(mqttServer, 1883);
  client.setCallback(mqttCallback);  
}

void mqttCallback(const char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
  Serial.print("Message arrived on topic: ");
  Serial.print(topic);
  Serial.print("Message: ");

  char * mqttTopic = "sms";
  String messageTemp;
  
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
    messageTemp += (char)payload[i];
  }
  Serial.println();

  // Feel free to add more if statements to control more GPIOs with MQTT

  // If a message is received on the topic esp32/output, you check if the message is either "on" or "off". 
  // Changes the output state according to the message
  if (String(topic) == String(mqttTopic)) {
    
  }
}

void mqttReconnect() {
  Serial.print("WiFi status = ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.status());
  
  char * clientId = "php";
  char * mqttUsername = "user";
  char * mqttPassword = "pass";
  char * mqttTopic = "sms";
 
  // Loop until we're reconnected
  while (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection ");
    // Attempt to connect
    if (client.connect(clientId, mqttUsername, mqttPassword)) {
      Serial.println("connected");
      // Subscribe
      
      boolean sub = client.subscribe("sms");
      Serial.println(sub);
    } else {
      Serial.print("failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(client.state());
      Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
      // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
  
  
}
```

When ESP32 publish a message in a topic, the message is received by subscriber (I create the subscriber with Java). But when it try to receive the message with callback, the client is disconnected.

I try to debug with edit library on file `PubSubClient.cpp`

```c
boolean PubSubClient::loop() {
    if (connected()) {
        unsigned long t = millis();
        if ((t - lastInActivity > MQTT_KEEPALIVE*1000UL) || (t - lastOutActivity > MQTT_KEEPALIVE*1000UL)) {
            if (pingOutstanding) {
                this->_state = MQTT_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT;
                _client->stop();
                return false;
            } else {
                buffer[0] = MQTTPINGREQ;
                buffer[1] = 0;
                _client->write(buffer,2);
                lastOutActivity = t;
                lastInActivity = t;
                pingOutstanding = true;
            }
        }
        if (_client->available()) {
            uint8_t llen;
            uint16_t len = readPacket(&llen);
            uint16_t msgId = 0;
            uint8_t *payload;
            if (len > 0) {
                lastInActivity = t;
                uint8_t type = buffer[0]&0xF0;
                if (type == MQTTPUBLISH) {
                    if (callback) {
                        uint16_t tl = (buffer[llen+1]<<8)+buffer[llen+2]; /* topic length in bytes */
                        memmove(buffer+llen+2,buffer+llen+3,tl); /* move topic inside buffer 1 byte to front */
                        buffer[llen+2+tl] = 0; /* end the topic as a 'C' string with \x00 */
                        char *topic = (char*) buffer+llen+2;
                        // msgId only present for QOS>0
                        if ((buffer[0]&0x06) == MQTTQOS1) {
                            msgId = (buffer[llen+3+tl]<<8)+buffer[llen+3+tl+1];
                            payload = buffer+llen+3+tl+2;
                            callback(topic,payload,len-llen-3-tl-2);

                            buffer[0] = MQTTPUBACK;
                            buffer[1] = 2;
                            buffer[2] = (msgId >> 8);
                            buffer[3] = (msgId & 0xFF);
                            _client->write(buffer,4);
                            lastOutActivity = t;

                        } else {
                            payload = buffer+llen+3+tl;
                            callback(topic,payload,len-llen-3-tl);
                        }
                    }
                } else if (type == MQTTPINGREQ) {
                    buffer[0] = MQTTPINGRESP;
                    buffer[1] = 0;
                    _client->write(buffer,2);
                } else if (type == MQTTPINGRESP) {
                    pingOutstanding = false;
                }
            } else if (!connected()) {
                // readPacket has closed the connection
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The `type` value is 208 which is `MQTTPINGRESP` not 48 which is `MQTTPUBLISH`.

So, where is the problem?

Is my library or my code?

I download library from https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/pubsubclient/

Comment: Well, you will get a MQTTPINGRESP first (and possibly multiple times over time), and later on, you may get what is published. Perhaps your code is not running the loop long enough. Another possiblity is that your client does not have the permission to subscribe to the topic. You have a line that prints the result of the subscribe. Is that giving you success ? I also noticed that you're not printing messageTemp after you accumulate it.

Comment: 'PubSubClient' is one the rare Arduino library that not only provide examples but a comprehensive [API document](https://pubsubclient.knolleary.net/api), the problem nowadays is that many people programming Arduino think reading API documentation or understand how MQTT works is optional. A MQTT client behind the scene send a PINGREQ at certain interval (KeepAlive) and expecting the broker to send back a PINGRESP. You didn't shown your complete code (loop() is missing), so we don't know whether you had `mqtt.loop()` in the loop or how you hand the reconnect? and what is the `rc` value return?

Comment: I replace the library with https://github.com/knolleary/pubsubclient because older library I used only allow to send 121 byte of message.

Now, my proram is work properly